# How to change face in particular theme locally?

Tags: faces, themes

The title says it all. How to change face in specific color theme locally, in my configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `custom-theme-set-faces` in a `with-eval-after-load` to easily customize a theme.

For example, this modifies `ample-theme` to have a lighter background and green keywords instead of the defaults.

```
(with-eval-after-load "ample-theme"
  (custom-theme-set-faces
   'ample
   '(default ((t (:foreground "#bdbdb3" :background "gray15"))))
   '(font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground "#818053"))))))
```