# Disable enlarged org-mode header appearance

Tags: org-mode, fonts, faces

I am using org-mode on Macintosh GNU Emacs version 24.5.1 in GUI mode and the headers are enlarged. I would like to disable this feature so they rendered in the default font size.

I have tried this...

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "monokai-theme"
  (custom-theme-set-faces
    'monokai
    '(org-level-1 ((t (:weight semi-bold :height 1.0))))
    '(org-level-2 ((t (:weight semi-bold :height 1.0))))
    '(org-level-3 ((t (:weight semi-bold :height 1.0))))
    '(org-level-4 ((t (:weight semi-bold :height 1.0))))))
```

Though this clobbers the theme and the colors are no loner rendered.

Should I accomplish it a different way?

Comment: Try experimenting with different themes.

Comment: **Very** closely related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19286/115 Just find the face you need to tweak and tweak it.

Comment: @KaushalModi I dug a little deeper and found you are right. The theme I am using, monokai-emacs, sets the face attribute `:height` of the `org-level`s to a larger size. Manually reseting them is the only way I have found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Org headings are controlled by the faces `org-level-1`, `org-level-2` etc. You can get to them via `M-x customize-face`. Unselecting the `height` attribute should set them to the default font size.

Comment: Placing the point over the text for which you want to know the applied face(s) and then doing `C-u C-x =` would help.

Comment: @KaushalModi yes, or more directly, `M-x describe-face`, which provides a link to the customize page.

Comment: Tyler and @KaushalModi both of those commands helped me see the attributes applied to the font. This was my first attempt to modify Emacs faces, and those commands will be vital if I do any more work with it.

Answer (score 15):

Okay I found a solution that worked for me.

```lisp
(defun my/org-mode-hook ()
  "Stop the org-level headers from increasing in height relative to the other text."
  (dolist (face '(org-level-1
                  org-level-2
                  org-level-3
                  org-level-4
                  org-level-5))
  (set-face-attribute face nil :weight 'semi-bold :height 1.0)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my/org-mode-hook)
```

This preserved the other `face-attributes` and did not clobber the theme like my original attempt. Also as a bonus it is not dependent on a single theme.

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to be using spacemacs, the theming layer supports overriding themes.

1. Add `theming` to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`
2. Add this to `dotspacemacs/user-init` substituing `zenburn` for the theme in question:

```lisp
(setq theming-modifications
      '((zenburn
        (org-level-1 :height 1.0)
        (org-level-2 :height 1.0)
        (org-level-3 :height 1.0)
        (org-level-4 :height 1.0)
        (org-level-5 :height 1.0))))
```

Comment: clean and working solution

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the end of your config file.

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
  '(hl-line ((t (:background "#476047604760" :height 1.0))))
  '(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit header-line :height 1.0))))
  '(org-level-2 ((t (:inherit header-line :height 1.0))))
  '(org-level-3 ((t (:inherit header-line :height 1.0)))))
```