# How to override background to black after load-theme?

Tags: colors

I am using the monokai theme from https://github.com/oneKelvinSmith/monokai-emacs, and I would like to override the background to be black. Following the override instructions, I tried:

```lisp
(setq monokai-background "#000000")
(load-theme 'monokai t)
```

However, this does not seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: What you typed worked for me.  I got a pure black background w/ monokai.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
(setq customize-set-variable "#000000")
(load-theme 'monokai t)
```

or better see "[How to change face in particular theme locally?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/how-to-change-face-in-particular-theme-locally)"

Comment: This looks wrong: there is no variable called `customize-set-variable` to set - it is a function, so do you mean `(customize-set-variable 'monokai-background '#000000)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the end of your .emacs file:

```
(set-background-color "black")
```

I've tried it on my machine and you can read more here: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_playing_with_color_theme.html

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the theme, THEN changing the background color. Your existing code allows the theme to set the color after you've changed it.

```
(load-theme 'monokai t)
(set-background-color "black")
```